# drupal - building the upper menu

Tags: drupal

How do I build and design an upper menu using drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most contrib Drupal Themes will allow you to do the following:

1. Navigate to
   http://YOURSITE//admin/build/themes/settings/YOURTHEME
2. Then toggle the primary menu and
   click save
3. Next go to
   http://YOURSITE/admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links/add
   and add a menu item called test
4. See your nice shiny new menu item at the top somewhere?
5. Now use your trusty CSS knowledge and your fantastic PHP/HTML skills and start designing by modifying your chosen starter template :)

Comment: Agreed. The menu at the top in default themes such as Garland, is usually populated by the "Primary Links" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking for, but try these modules:

http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus - Nice Menus

http://drupal.org/project/superfish - Superfish

They should do the trick.